# Is there a sparse Span<T> for multiple Memory<T> sections?

Tags: c#, .net, system.memory

Consider:

```
        public struct Foo
        {
            public float value;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var array = new Foo[10];

            var block1 = new Memory<Foo>(array, 0, 3);
            var block2 = new Memory<Foo>(array, 4, 6);

            var span1 = block1.Span;
            var span2 = block2.Span;

            foreach (ref var  f in span1) { /* do work */ }
            foreach (ref var  f in span2) { /* do work */ }

            var blocks = new[] { block1, block2 };

            foreach (var block in blocks)
            {
                foreach (ref var f in block.Span)
                {
                    /* do work */
                }
            }

            // preferred would be:
            foreach (ref var f in new Span<Foo>(blocks))
            {
                /* do work */
            }
        }
```

Is there a span structure that lets you cover multiple memory blocks? I could write a custom enumerator, but calling Memory.Span for each element is slow.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve the problem at the wrong level of abstraction. If you have multiple `Memory`s and can make no assumption about them, there's not much you can do other than accessing them as spans in order. If, on the other hand, you *are* operating on contiguous memory, there'd be no need to pass multiple `Memory`s -- just pass one with an appropriate range, or turn it into one span on access and slice that as necessary.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yeah you're totally right. This is really just a utility/sugar thing. I can do it the way I've written, by looping through them, but I wasn't sure if there was a cleaner mechanism to express this pattern or not.

Comment: Nested foreach loops is probably the best way to go here. You could use `foreach (var f in blocks.SelectMany(b => b.Span.ToArray()))` , but that's going to be slower

Comment: The simplest solution is sometimes the best solution. The way you have it written is actually not terrible and is perfectly understandable. If you're looking for a one-line solution, another option might be to cast to List and use [List<T>.ForEach( )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-5.0) like  `blocks.ToList().ForEach(block => block.Span.ToList().ForEach(f => /* Action */));`. But that's probably slower and a lot less readable for the next dev. The way you have it with nested foreach loops is probably just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you obtain your data but you might consider:
[ReadOnlySequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.readonlysequence-1?view=net-6.0)